# How can I pad values into array 1 with values from array 2 at indices from array 3?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, dictionary, pad

I am trying to pad values to a numpy array. The array is initially filled with ones, and my goal is to overwrite the values of ones at specified indices with values from another array.

```
import numpy as np
# get initial array of ones
mask = np.ones(10)
# get values to overwrite ones at indices
values = [10, 30, 50.5]
# get indices for which values will replace ones 
idx_pad = [1, 6, 7]

print(mask)
>> [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
```

What I want to get is:

```
>> [ 1  10  1  1  1  1  30  50.5  1  1 ]
```

I think there's a way to do this using an `OrderedDict`, though I'm still trying to figure it out. I'm also hopeful that there is a fast approach via `numpy`. I hope to apply this example to my actual dataset, for which `len(idx_pad) = 10322` and `len(mask) = 69268`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `mask[idx_pad] = values`?

Comment: I didn't realize I could use multiple indices like that, I was wrongly under the assumption that only a single value could be passed like that. Thanks! If you post as an answer, I will accept.

Comment: Would encourage you to post your findings in a self answered post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution via @Divakar.

```
import numpy as np
# get initial array of ones
mask = np.ones(10)
# get values to overwrite ones at indices
values = [10, 30, 50.5]
# get indices for which values will replace ones
idx_pad = [1, 6, 7]

print(mask)
>> [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]

# replace values at indices in idx_pad
mask[idx_pad] = values

print(mask)
>> [  1.   10.    1.    1.    1.    1.   30.   50.5   1.    1. ]
```